# Find friends page with user NSContacts is very slow + "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread"

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous, parse-platform

I'm trying to develop a find friends page that checks if any of the user's contacts has already joined my platform. It shouldn't take too long, however it take about 2 to 3 minutes which makes me think there's something wrong with it. I have a couple ideas on what that could be :

- I'm messing up somewhere in my asynchronous call. This is my main hypothesis, although I'm not sure where. That's very likely to be the cause though also because on the console I get the following error :

> *This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This
>   will cause an exception in a future release.*

I think that is hapenning inside one of the for loops since I get the error multiple times.

- My other idea is that the delay has something to do with the constraints since I also get :

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint NSLayoutConstraint:0x127c2ab00 UITextView:0x127011000'Name lastname created ...'.centerY == UIView:0x1278c21b0.centerY>

```
            let store = CNContactStore()

            //Find all  the contacts and store them in an instance variable

            store.requestAccessForEntityType(.Contacts) { granted, error in
                guard granted else {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        // user didn't grant authorization, so tell them to fix that in settings
                        print(error)
                    }
                    return
                }

                // get the contacts
                self.showActivityIndicator()

                var localcontacts = [CNContact]()
                let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactIdentifierKey, CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle(.FullName), CNContactPhoneNumbersKey])

                request.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.GivenName

                do {
                    try store.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(request) { contact, stop in
                        if !contact.phoneNumbers.isEmpty {
                            localcontacts.append(contact)
                        }

                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }

                self.cncontacts = localcontacts

                var cs = [contactObject]()

                for contact in self.cncontacts {
                    let formatter = CNContactFormatter()
                    formatter.style = .FullName
                    let name = formatter.stringFromContact(contact)
                    var numbers = [String]()
                    if (contact.isKeyAvailable(CNContactPhoneNumbersKey)) {
                        for phoneNumber:CNLabeledValue in contact.phoneNumbers {
                            let a = phoneNumber.value as! CNPhoneNumber
                            let number = a.stringValue.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "-", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
                            numbers.append(number)
                        }
                    }
                    if numbers.count > 0 {
                    let c : contactObject = contactObject.init()
                    c.name = name!
                    c.numbers = numbers
                    cs.append(c)

                    }

                }


                self.contacts = cs
                //For each contactObject check if there's an user associated with it

                for localcontact in self.contacts {



                    print(localcontact.name)

                    for number in localcontact.numbers {

                        print(number)

                        if number.hasPrefix("+1") || number.hasPrefix("(") || number.hasPrefix("1"){
                            //Is american phone number 
                            var formattednumber = number

                            if number.hasPrefix("+1") {

                                if number.hasPrefix("+1 "){
                                    formattednumber = number.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+1 ", withString: "")
                                    formattednumber = formattednumber.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
                                }
                                else if number.hasPrefix("+1-"){
                                    formattednumber = number.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+1-", withString: "")
                                }
                                else {
                                    formattednumber = number.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+1", withString: "")
                                }



                            }

                            else if number.hasPrefix("1"){
                                if number.hasPrefix("1-") {
                                formattednumber = number.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("1-", withString: "")
                                }
                                else{
                                    formattednumber = number.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("1 ", withString: "")
                                }
                            }

                            formattednumber = formattednumber.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "-")

                            print(formattednumber)
                            let userquery = PFUser.query()
                            userquery?.whereKey("phone", equalTo: formattednumber)
                            userquery?.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (user, error) in
                                if error == nil {
                                    if let user = user as? PFUser {

                                        localcontact.userid = user.objectId!


                                    }
                                }
                            })



                        }


                    }



                }

                self.hideActivityIndicator()
                let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.contacts)
                userDefaults.setObject(encodedData, forKey: "contacts")
                userDefaults.synchronize()
                self.tableView.reloadData()


            }
```

If you have any suggestion or thoughts about what I could be doing wrong I would really appreciate it if you could let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is

self.showActivityIndicator()

self.hideActivityIndicator()

self.tableView.reloadData()

are all trying to modify the layout of the UI and hence the warning.

Try doing them in

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
}

blocks

Comment: I agree, I thought so too and I tried commenting the hideAcitivityIndicator() and showActivityIndicator() but nothing changed. I haven't tried to remove tableview.reloaddata() as I wouldn't know how else I could reload the data once all the data is loaded in the array. Do you have any suggestion on how I could do that in another way?

Comment: Did you try                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.tableView.reloadData() } instead of just self.tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Should that be inside the asynchrous call or outside ?

Comment: That actually worked, I called it inside the method! Thanks a lot!